# Any way to use DNS/mDNS with Windows Mobile Hotspot?

Tags: windows, mobile-hotspot

Windows 11 provides the feature "Mobile Hotspot", which I use to connect my Android phone and PC and share files on FTP/SFTP (PC establishes the connection to the Android SFTP server).

Mobile Hotspot automatically assigns a private dynamic IP address to the device. The phone is reachable from the PC through the Mobile Hotspot interface by the assigned IP address. However, because this IP is dynamic, I have to keep updating it in the PC FTP program when connecting to the phone FTP server every time the IP changes.

In the attached picture you can see Windows correctly showing the device name "hetchel" along its IP address. However, pinging "hetchel.local" or "hetchel" doesn't work.

Since Windows already "knows" the device name, is there any way to access that device without having to use its IP address? (the goal being to use a name that can be relied on even when the IP changes. I have no problems on using an IP directly if it's static)

Note: I'm on a corporate laptop, I can't enable a custom DCHP+DNS server.

[Screenshot showing the device name and IP on Windows Mobile Hotspot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhZRl.png)

Comment: Is your need related to Corporate Software perhaps?  I connect my Windows 11 machine using my iPhone and everything on my Windows 11 machine connects whatever IP I get from the iPhone.

Comment: You would have to modify the hosts file.  Since `192.168.137.154` is a static intranet that you can configure to never change that would be my suggestion. This would allow you to simply `ssh user@hetchel` if you wanted. Of course you could also just use that static intranet address. Editing the hosts file obviously will require Administrative access on the device.

Comment: @John, No it's not a corporate thing, as explained, I use it to transfer files between my phone and PC using FTP, which is really convenient. Except when the IP changes.

Comment: @Ramhound That's the catch, as explained in the post, the IP is not static, is dynamic. The problem is not having to use the IP, I'm perfectly happy using an IP, as long as it's static.

Having to manually update it in my FTP program every time the IP changes is what I would like to avoid.

Adding it to hosts files would not make the address static.

Also, it can't be made static because it's completely managed by Windows Mobile Hotspot, it's not configurable.

Comment: When you referred to the dynamic address I assume you were talking about the IP address assigned by the mobile provider. Unless you modify the hosts file you cannot cannot to the device name.

Comment: @Ramhound I have edited the question to clarify that the IP addres is the one assigned by the Mobile Hotspot service. Thank you for your answer. Apologies for not being clear enough.